# How to update rows in SQL that contain certain json data?

Tags: sql, json

I am trying to update password values but at the same time preserve all the other values.

For example, the only change in the image below would be "johndoePassword" to "*****".

How do I write a SQL statement that would do this dynamically in several rows?

I have looked into JSON_MODIFY (Transact-SQL) but can't figure out how to apply that to several existing rows and how to get to the child key/value pairs.

```
SELECT Id, RouteValues 
FROM MyDatabase
WHERE RouteValues like '%password%'
```

[image]

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) You should not just request a ready solution. SO is for helping solve specific errors, after you've shown your effort solving them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with:

```
UPDATE dbo.MyDatabase
SET RouteValues=JSON_MODIFY(RouteValues, '$.model.password', '*****')
WHERE ISJSON(RouteValues) > 0 AND RouteValues like '%password%'
```